# Is it possible to keep a column in excel 2016 in sync between sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to split the columns on my server list over multiple sheets within same file. Is it possible to have a master server list on sheet1 and on sheet2 the same master list can appear? to add to that, if i add a server to the list on Sheet1 i want it to show up on sheet2.

I have only basic Excel skills so would need some references to information so i can read up on what suggestions is being presented :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Indirect()` to make sure the formula doesn't change.

Say your master list will be in column A of Sheet1.

On Sheet2, put this in `A1` and drag down however far you need:

`=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&row())`.

Then if you move anything, add rows, etc in Sheet1, it won't make the Sheet2 formulas adjust relatively:

[image]

You may want to do

```
=IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&row())<>"",INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&row()),"")
```

to hide any `0` that appear.

Comment: This is impressive if only for the animation.  :-)  +1